# Xcode 14.3 failed to verify module interface of 'project'

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, xcode14.3

There were a lot of issues when trying to run the app after upgrading Xcode to the latest, `14.3` version.

The one I am facing now is:
`failed to verify module interface of 'projectName' due to the errors above; the textual interface may be broken by project issues or a compiler bug`
along with `No such module Firebase`

`Edit`: Seems like it is not up to Firebase nor any other pod since people are having the same issue for different pods.
I have tried these things but no success:

- updating all pods to the latest version
- updating Cocoapods to the latest version 1.12.0
- cleaning build folder and derived data, as always
- updating CommandLineTools to the newest version(14E222 > 14E222b)
- downgrading CommandLineTools to the previous Xcode 14.3's version 14C18

[image: 1]

Comment: I have the same issue, maybe do you find solution?

Comment: Two things, please include errors as text, not screen shots. Then, did you clean your build folder? Did you update your podfile and install a newer version of Firebase to match the updated XCode?

Comment: Having the same issue with Xcode 14.3. Not with Firebase but with Airship.

Comment: Same here in one of my targets.

Comment: @АлексейСмольский Unfortunately I did not. So it is definitely not up to any pod since we are getting the same error for different pods. I have also tried updating all the pods but still having the same issue.

Comment: I found reason https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11808
We need to waiting for 1.12.1 version

Comment: Temporary fix is to download `Xcode 14.2`.

Comment: same behavior inside my project. same thread here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75955074/swiftverifyemittedmoduleinterface-normal-arm64-issue-building-release-with-crypt/76003381#76003381

@stackich is right, compiling und Xcode14.2 all is working

Comment: The problem is this new feature in xCode 14.3. The Xcode 14.3 includes a new module verifier that generates diagnostics for issues in a framework’s modules. (97345247). If we know how to disable it, then we have a solution for this issue.

Comment: I am also having the same issue

Comment: @stackich that didn't fix for me

Comment: @TseringNorbu you meant 14.2 installation did not help you? please write in one comment. You may confirm that Command Line Tools is using Xcode 14.2 version , too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add `-no-verify-emitted-module-interface` to Other Swift Flags to your Build Settings if you are using SPM.

Comment: verify modules was added in Xcode 14.3 I’m not sure disabling stuff is always the answer.

Comment: @lukaskasa I can confirm that this is also the solution for Cocoapods. Question - should we keep only this in Other Swift Flags(remove all other staff that was there before)?

Comment: Lol. Does anyone actually know why this works? What are the side effects?

Comment: we tried this step 20+ times, and each time we have done step-1;

step-1
Product->clean build folder 
Product->run

but when we tried without doing  step-1  after 20 times, its successfully ran, 
i don't know why 

 but working fine now thankyou

Answer (score 4):

If you use cocoapods
you can insert this code at `Podfile` file end

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS'] = '-no-verify-emitted-module-interface'
    end
  end
end
```

This is an easy way to add `'-no-verify-emitted-module-interface'`
then run `pod install` again

is work for me at xcode v14.3.1

Answer (score 3):

I did this in two steps:

1. I created Release.xcconfig
2. added one line: OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS =
   -no-verify-emitted-module-interface

How it looks in Xcode:

[image]

Additionally, I added this flag:

```
BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES
```

[image]

I found this solution [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/64669).

Answer (score 1):

We got the same issue in my code, and I changed the:

```
BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION = No
```

…in project build setting, and then it's working in my side.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I added @_implementationOnly when importing the library and it stopped happening.

Comment: did that worked for simulator too?