# SwiftVerifyEmittedModuleInterface normal arm64 Issue building release with CryptorRSA | Xcode 14.3

Tags: swift, xcode, kitura

I am trying to build a release xcframework for distribution that uses SwiftJWT via Swift Package Manager:
[image: SwiftJWT SPM dependency]

I am able to build fine confirmed for Xcode 14.2.0, 14.0.1, 13.4.1, 13.2.1, and 13.1.0. But when I try building with Xcode 14.3, I get the following error:

```
** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    SwiftVerifyEmittedModuleInterface normal arm64 Verifying\ emitted\ module\ interface\ CryptorRSA.private.swiftinterface /Users/tj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VNWebSDK-fwdasyvrfoacjledmziziwepgjrj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VNWebSDK/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/CryptorRSA.build/Release-iphoneos/CryptorRSA.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CryptorRSA.private.swiftinterface (in target 'CryptorRSA' from project 'CryptorRSA')
    SwiftVerifyEmittedModuleInterface normal arm64 Verifying\ emitted\ module\ interface\ CryptorRSA.swiftinterface /Users/tj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VNWebSDK-fwdasyvrfoacjledmziziwepgjrj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VNWebSDK/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/CryptorRSA.build/Release-iphoneos/CryptorRSA.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CryptorRSA.swiftinterface (in target 'CryptorRSA' from project 'CryptorRSA')
(2 failures)
```

I've tried several things, like setting `-Xfrontend -module-interface-preserve-types-as-written` in `OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS` and excluding architectures. I can't get it to work.

Could this be due to a conflict/duplication between a module and class name inside of CryptorRSA, or is there something I can do to get this to build the xcframework in Xcode 14.3?

> **Note**: CryptorRSA is a dependency of SwiftJWT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not entirely certain of what the issue is, but the reason this is failing in Xcode 14.3 is due to this from the Xcode 14.3 release notes:

- Xcode 14.3 includes a new module verifier that generates diagnostics for issues in a framework’s modules. (97345247)

Something in the dependency is failing module validation.

I am now suffering from this failure in my project but due to a different reason. I am currently looking to see if there is a way to disable this verifier for the time being until I can resolve the underlying issue.

**UPDATE**:

There is a flag, `-no-verify-emitted-module-interface` that can be applied to the `Other Swift Flags` Swift Compiler Flag which disables the module verifier during the build process.

Found it mentioned on this Swift issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/64669).

There are a few variations of what the flag should be listed in that issue, however, what I have noted above is what worked for me with Xcode 14.3.

Comment: What's even more strange is in my case, I can still build my SDK in Xcode 14.2, and then I can integrate the SDK built in Xcode 14.2 into projects and run and build those integrating apps in Xcode 14.3. So that's really strange.